# Shower pump cuts out when switched to rain head

Tags: shower

We've just a new shower fitted using a Salamander CT50+XTRA pump with a rain shower head and an ordinary shower head controlled with a diverting valve.

We have a gravity fed cold feed from the loft and the hot feed comes from the immmersion tank via the surrey flange that was fitted by the plumber.

If we use the 'ordinary' shower head all is fine, however if we switch to the rain shower head it works until you increase the temperature at which point after 30 seconds or so the pump shuts off and we get no water.

The pump is rated at 1.5 bar, so my question is, if we upgraded the pump would this help? or is there potentially something else going on?

Thankyou in advance,
J

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. What is being pumped here? Does the rain head use more water than the ordinary head?  And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: Are you saying you have a pump on the hot water, but gravity feed on the cold water?  Is this a thermostatic mixing valve (one knob or joystick) or two separate valves?

Comment: Hello both and thankyou for the welcome.

Comment: Hello both and thankyou for the welcome. To try and answer your questions, both hot and cold are being pumped. I'm not sure how I would tell if the rain head uses more than the ordinary head?. The valve has two controls, one stops and starts the flow and the other controls the temperature. Thankyou for helping.

Comment: It almost sounds like there is a safety pressure switch to prevent the system from running when their is not enough pressure. Use a bucket and measure how much time for each head to fill to a line on the bucket, of the rain head fills in less time it is using more water.